# How can I get fix my Ubuntu install and reclaim USB device control?

Tags: boot, networking, 20.04, usb

I've installed a 2nd storage device to run windows from on a machine I had Ubuntu 20.04 already installed. The idea is to be able to switch OS, but keep storage devices separate.

After installing Windows and rebooting, selecting the Ubuntu drive from the device boot list at startup I noticed a few errors I've not seen before:

[image: ubuntu errors]

```
[2.738207] xhci hcd 0000:24:00.0: init 0000:24:00.0 fail, -16
[2.739256] xhci_hcd 0000:29:00.1: init 0000:29:00.1 fail, -16
[2.739344] xhci_hcd 0000:29:00.3: init 0000:29:00.3 fail, -16
/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean, 1248701/116178944 files, 59804647/464709120 blocks
[ 6.816557) iwlwifi 0000:26:00.0: pcim_iomap_regions_request_all failed
[7.206276]
```

I can see the Desktop however the (USB) keyboard and mouse no longer work.
Additionally I no longer see the machine on the WLAN to SSH into it.

**Update**

Luckily Ethernet still works and I can get the machine online/SSH/VNC into it.

Via `dmesg` I can see more details:

```bash
[    2.731813] ahci 0000:26:00.0: version 3.0
[    2.731894] ahci: probe of 0000:26:00.0 failed with error -22
[    2.731940] acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
[    2.731952] xhci_hcd 0000:23:00.0: init 0000:23:00.0 fail, -16
[    2.731958] fbcon: Taking over console
[    2.732020] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 128x48
[    2.732045] ahci: probe of 0000:27:00.0 failed with error -22
[    2.732083] acpi PNP0C14:03: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
[    2.732244] ahci: probe of 0000:29:00.0 failed with error -22
[    2.732564] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:2a:00.0
[    2.732575] xhci_hcd: probe of 0000:23:00.0 failed with error -16
[    2.732806] acpi PNP0C14:04: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
[    2.732898] xhci_hcd 0000:28:00.1: init 0000:28:00.1 fail, -16
[    2.732900] xhci_hcd: probe of 0000:28:00.1 failed with error -16
[    2.732966] xhci_hcd 0000:28:00.3: init 0000:28:00.3 fail, -16
[    2.732967] xhci_hcd: probe of 0000:28:00.3 failed with error -16
[    2.733044] xhci_hcd 0000:2c:00.3: xHCI Host Controller
[    2.733052] xhci_hcd 0000:2c:00.3: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    2.733136] xhci_hcd 0000:2c:00.3: hcc params 0x0260ffe5 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000000000000410
[    2.733497] xhci_hcd 0000:2c:00.3: xHCI Host Controller
...
[    6.791039] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    6.791732] iwlwifi 0000:25:00.0: pcim_iomap_regions_request_all failed
[    6.791768] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:25:00.0 failed with error -22
```

I've tried the following (with no joy):

- `update-grub`
- `boot-repair` with default options
- `boot-repair` with "Purge kernels then reinstall last kernel": the command just silently fails (no obvious errors noticeable, but command never completes)
- set BIOS settings to defaults
- Installed a different kernel (`5.15.95-051595-generic`) via `ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh`

What can I do to fix this ? Is there a way to get USB (keyboard/WiFi) working again without having to reinstall Ubuntu ? How can I find out what exactly when wrong (why would installing Win11 mess it up and how) ?

**Update 2**

I've tried the recovery media that came with the machine, then tried downloading a [fresh 20.04 image](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.6/) and reflashing the USB, but ended up with the same errors + some new ones (nouveau: unknown chipset and stdin (probably because USB input doesn't work ?):

[image: xhci_hcd fail errors + stdin: Invalid errors]

```
xhci_hcd 0000:24:00.0: init 0000:24:00.0 fail, -16
xhci_hcd 0000:24:00.0: init 0000:24:00.0 fail, -16
xhci_hcd 0000:24:00.1: init 0000:24:00.1 fail, -16
xhci_hcd 0000:24:00.3: init 0000:24:00.3 fail, -16
nouveau 0000:41:00.0: unknown chipset (192000a1)
stdin:Invalid argument
stdin:Invalid argument
stdin:Invalid argument
...
Unable to find a medium container a live file system
Attempt interactive netboot from a URL?
yes no (default yes):
```

(The being I can't type anything without USB working)

Comment: Have you tried the newest version of Ubuntu, 23.04 ?

Comment: I have not, no. I have been using a few Deep Learning frameworks that rely on PyTorch/CUDA support and most are tested/rely on 20.04 (not many use 23.04 currently) which is why I'm hesitant about switching versions.